# I can't run my react native project app on Android Studio emulator

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, terminal, react-native

I've been trying to learn to make an app using react native on Visual Studio Code. I also created an Android emulator in Android Studio and ANDROID_HOME variable in Advanced System Settings on Windows 10. However when running the app on Visual Code by typing the following command in terminal: react-native run-android, the emulator started and it displays a virtual smartphone, but doesn't show the app. It only displays the android home screen and several preinstalled apps, although I did everything like what a tutorial on YouTube said. Please help me!

Comment: Can you provide the log of the terminal? The app does not open automatically but did you check if it gets installed?  Probably it is a adb error.

Comment: Terminal said that it was installing the app and then it launched NodeJS window, black Android emulator window and the virtual Android smartphone.

Comment: (node:9276) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Jetifier found 944 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Starting Daemon